# Discriminating users without authentication in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am currently writing a comment system for websites with Spring Boot that will be based on a simple REST API.

In order to let people delete or update comments they posted earlier, I'd like to store a unique token in a Cookie to remember/identify them. Users are *not* required to register in order to post comments. When a user deletes the cookie or when it expires, there will be no way to get back permissions to delete/modify a comment.

Of course it is possible to implement such a functionality by myself using filters, but I wanted to know if there is a standard way for doing this in Spring (probably using Spring Security)? I thought this would be a common scenario, but all examples I could find include authentication information like username/password.

Comment: It looks like a strange design to use a cookie that identify a browser to hold permissions. What is closer is the standard *remember me* option in Spring Framework, but it is only used after a successful authentication - and is only used as a hint for next connection...

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved by creating a custom implementation of `SecurityContextRepository`.

1. Create an implementation of `SecurityContextRepository` that loads authentication information from a cookie.
2. Create an implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` to check if the cookie contains a valid value.  A prefix and/or a suffix may be added to the cookie value and the value may be encrypted to ensure authenticity and prevent impersonation.

I have a [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-rest/tree/master/api/src/main/scala/org/example/api/security) that demonstrates  the components to be implemented.  The sample stores authentication information in an in-memory cache but it can be stored in `HttpSession` or any other data store as required.  The code is in Scala but should be readable for Java programmers.

Answer (score 4):

With Spring Security you can write a custom Filter to achieve the functionality that you need. For example check [RestTokenValidationFilter](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/blob/1.5.3/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy), this one reads the Authorization Header and validates whether the token is valid or not by looking the token in database.

You could use the similar pattern. Instead of reading the Authorization Header, you could read the cookie and Authenticate the User.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily override the Spring security implementation

1. You have unprotected url say authenticate, in which you will send user name and password to the server.
2. Authenticate user based on username and password
3. Create secure token.
4. Send token in every request to access resources.

Here is complete working example:
https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity